# Complex challenge about complexity and intersection

Tags: javascript, math, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

**Preface**

Notice: This question is about complexity. I use here a complex design pattern, which you don't need to understand in order to understand the question. I could have simplified it more, but I chose to keep it relatively untouched for the sake of preventing mistakes. The code is written in TypeScript which is a super-set of JavaScript.

---

**The code**

Regard the following class:

```
export class ConcreteFilter implements Filter {
    interpret() {
        // rows is a very large array
        return (rows: ReportRow[], filterColumn: string) => {
            return rows.filter(row => {
                // I've hidden the implementation for simplicity, 
                // but it usually returns either an empty array or a very short one.
                }
            }).map(row => <string>row[filterColumn]);
        }
    }
}
```

It receives an array of report row, then it filters the array by some logic that I've hidden. Finally it does not return the whole row, but only one stringy column that is mentioned in `filterColumn`.

Now, take a look at the following function:

```
function interpretAnd (filters: Filter[]) {
    return (rows: ReportRow[], filterColumn: string) => {
        var runFilter = filters[0].interpret();
        var intersectionResults = runFilter(rows, filterColumn);

        for (var i=1; i<filters.length; i++) {
            runFilter = filters[i].interpret();
            var results = runFilter(rows, filterColumn);
            intersectionResults = _.intersection(intersectionResults, results);
        }

        return intersectionResults;
    }
}
```

It receives an array of filters, and returns a distinct array of all the "filterColumn"s that the filters returned.

In the for loop, I get the results (string array) from every filter, and then make an intersection operation.

---

**The problem**

The report row array is large so every `runFilter` operation is expensive (while on the other hand the filter array is pretty short). I want to iterate the report row array as fewer times as possible. Additionally, the `runFilter` operation is very likely to return zero results or very few.

---

**Explanation**

Let's say that I have 3 filters, and 1 billion report rows. the internal iterration, i.e. the iteration in `ConcreteFilter`, will happen 3 billion times, even if the first execution of `runFilter` returned 0 results, so I have 2 billion redundant iterations.

So, I could, for example, check if `intersectionResults` is empty in the beginning of every iteration, and if so, then break the loop. But I'm sure that there are better solutions mathematically.

Also if the first `runFIlter` exectuion returned say 15 results, I would expect the next exectuion to receive an array of only 15 report rows, meaning I want the intersection operation to influence the input of the next call to `runFilter`.

I can modify the report row array after each iteration, but I don't see how to do it in an efficient way that won't be even more expensive than now.

A good solution would be to remove the `map` operation, and then passing the already filtered array in each operation instead of the entire array, but I'm not allowed to do it because I must not change the results format of Filter interface.

---

**My question**

I'd like to get the best solution you could think of as well as an explanation.

Thanks a lot in advance to every one who would spend his time trying to help me.

Comment: If `runFilter` is the thing taking the most time, the first thing to try would be to replace the `foo.filter().map()` call with a for loop. If everything matches the filter you're looping the array twice.

Does the order of the results matter?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I could merge the filter and the map, but what's the difference? Both are O(n). Anyway the critical thing is in the interpretAnd function. That is where I can really make a big difference.

Comment: It's a matter of order - a well known behavior in SQL.  You should perform the operation that reduces the size of the set the most first.  It minimizes the work done by the second operation.  Both might be O(n), but you may be able to reduce the size of n for the second operation more with one sequence than the other.

Comment: @duffymo this is exactly what I do. As you can see, the filter is before the map, so the order is right. Anyway my question is about improving the interpretAnd function, not the ColumnValueFilter class.

Comment: @duffymo I've edited my question to make it more short and to the point.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I've edited my question to make it more short and to the point.

Comment: Your question doesn't match up with your statement. You're saying that `runFilter` is expensive, but it is "very likely to return zero results or very few". In that case, it seems like you're optimizing in the wrong spot. If it's returning few results, then getting the intersection should be reasonably cheap, no? Also, as I asked before, does the order of the results matter?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli OK now I understand what's not clear. In the for loop inside "interpretAnd" I iterate the filters array, and for each filter I call to "runFilter" with the entire report row array. So let's say I have 3 filters, and 1 billion report rows, the internal iterration, i.e. the iteration in the ConcreteFilter class, will happen 3 billion times, even if in the first execution of the runFilter returned 0 results, so I have 2 billion redundant iterations.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli And if the first runFIlter exectuion returned say 15 results, I would expect the next exectuion to receive an array of only 15 report rows, meaning I want the intersection operation to influence the input of the next call to runFilter. BTW to your question: the order doesn't matter for me.

Comment: If you must stick with that filter interface, then that's very unfortunate because it would be a whole lot easier if you could actually return the row. Is there any other information about the data that is relevant? If you have no way to work back from the string value returned from the filter to get you the row, I don't see any way to prevent iterating over them all again.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I edited my question now to contain all the relevant information I could think of. Yes it would be a lot easier if I could return a row but I can't. I'm sure there's a best solution for that mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how effective this will be, but here's one possible approach you can take. If you preprocess the rows by the filter column you'll have a way to retrieve the matched rows. If you typically have more than 2 filters then this approach may be more beneficial, however it will be more memory intensive. You could branch the approach depending on the number of filters. There may be some TS constructs that are more useful, not very familiar with it. There are some comments in the code below:

```
var map = {};

// Loop over every row, keep a map of rows with a particular filter value.
allRows.forEach(row => {
    const v = row[filterColumn];
    let items;
    items = map[v] = map[v] || [];
    items.push(row)
});

let rows = allRows;
filters.forEach(f => {
    // Run the filter and return the unique set of matched strings
    const matches = unique(f.execute(rows, filterColumn));
    // For each of the matched strings, go and look up the remaining rows and concat them for the next filter.
    rows = [].concat(...matches.reduce(m => map[v]));
});

// Loop over the rows that made it all the way through, extract the value and then unique() the collection
return unique(rows.map(row => row[filterColumn]));
```

Thinking about it some more, you could use a similar approach but just do it on a per filter basis:

```
let rows = allRows;
filters.forEach(f => {
    const matches = f.execute(rows, filterColumn);
    let map = {};
    matches.forEach(m => {
        map[m] = true;
    });

    rows = rows.filter(row => !!map[row[filterColumn]]);
});
return distinctify(rows.map(row => row[filterColumn]));
```

Comment: I usually have between one to three filters, but sometimes more. Exactly two filters is quite common. I liked your answer, I voted up, but I will only accept an answer that either improves efficiency even with only 2 filters, or proves (mathematically or in a different way) that a better answer can't be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "proves that a better answer can't be". Proves in what way?